# AnyChart with Firebase Android

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, anychart

Hi i currently doing assignment and stuck at his issue, i was Trying to retrieve data from firebase using anychart with ValueDataEntry but get this error

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to int

Below Are the code for history.java and Expense.class.

```
public void setupPieChart() {
    Pie pie = AnyChart.pie();
    List<DataEntry> dataEntries = new ArrayList<>();
    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Expense");
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds:snapshot.getChildren()){
               Expense expense = ds.getValue(Expense.class);
               dataEntries.add(new ValueDataEntry(expense.getItem(), expense.getAmount()));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

    pie.data(dataEntries);
    anyChartView.setChart(pie);
}
```

public class Expense

```
public Expense() {
}

public Expense(String id, String item, int amount) {
    this.id = id;
    this.item = item;
    this.amount = amount;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getItem() {
    return item;
}

public void setItem(String item) {
    this.item = item;
}

public int getAmount() {
    return amount;
}

public void setAmount(int amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}
```

}

Comment: I think the value for the amount is in String in Firebase, So you need to change the datatype as a String in model class, Try this hope It will work

Comment: well now its says Cannot resolve constructor 'ValueDataEntry(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

this is the line of code: dataEntries.add(new ValueDataEntry(expense.getAmount(), expense.getItem()));

Comment: Use something like this - dataEntries.add(new ValueDataEntry(expense.getItem(),Integer.parseInt(expense.getAmount())));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

I think the value for the amount is in String in Firebase, So you need to change the datatype as a String in the model class.

Then -

```
dataEntries.add(new ValueDataEntry(expense.getItem(),Integer.parseInt(expense.getAmount())));
```

Comment: Thanks now it does not crash for now but instead is this
E/cr_PlatformSer-Internal: UsageReporting query failed
E/cr_PlatformSer-Internal: Unable to determine Safe Browsing user opt-in preference

"The activity is not showing the chart"